# javascript regex replace help!

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

my string is like this

```
coder<coder@gmail.com>
```

i want `coder@gmail.com` back

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var rcpt = 'coder<coder@gmail.com>';
var addy = rcpt.match(/<([^>]*)>/)[1];
// addy = 'coder@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Escaping `<` and `>` is not necessary: `/<([^>]*)>/` or equivalently `/<(.*?)>/` or even `/<(.*)>/` if we assume that this is the complete string and it contains only valid email adresses.

Comment: i actually looked for a solution like say rcpt.replace(regex) okey still this yeilds result i'm happy

Comment: @Felix: ah yes, thanks.  There's several regex dialects where it is necessary, and none where escaped `\<` or `\>` mess up the regex, so I routinely escape them anyway.  I’ve edited the post to remove them.

Comment: @Harish: you can easily use a similar regular expression with the replace function: `addy = rcpt.replace(/^.*<([^>]*)>.*$/, '$1');`

Answer (score 2):

`str.split("<")[1].split(">")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Do you know http://regexlib.com/ ?

It's a site full of regex with a regex coach to try your regex.

Also you can replace manually like this:

```
str.remove( string.indexOf('<'), 0 ) 
str.remove( 0, string.indexOf('>') )
```

or something equals...

Comment: That will yield 'codercoder@gmail.com', which probably isn't what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

try str.replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">


document.write(str.replace("coder<coder@gmail.com>
", "coder@gmail.com"));

</script>
```

Comment: Check the question i told like this ! not exactly this!